# Stripe Coupon Durations and Subscription Billing Intervals

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to understand how Coupons work in Stripe, when applied to Subscriptions with different billing intervals, and the official docs are pretty unclear.

Stripe lets you create subscription `plans` that bill on different `interval`s (`daily`, `monthly`, `yearly`, `weekly`, `every 3 months`, `every 6 months`, or `custom`).

Subscriptions can (optionally) have trial periods, measured in days.

Stripe also lets you create `coupons`, which apply to those subscription plans for a certain `duration` (`once`, `repeating`, or `forever`). If you choose `repeating`, you can also pass a numeric `duration_in_months` parameter, which sets the duration of the discount.

Okay, so the confusing part of this is that subscriptions and coupons can have completely different intervals: I could create a subscription with a 25-day free trial, a weekly billing period, and a coupon with a duration of two months. If the customer applied the coupon on the 9th day of the trial, how many invoices would incorporate the discount?

How does the logic work for figuring out whether a coupon is still active?

Comment: That's a great question. Very sad it is not in the API yet. However it should be possible by using 'invoice.create' webhooks to remove the coupon by your custom logic

Answer (score 4):

A coupon with a duration of 2 months would mean that the coupon will be applied to all invoices generated for that customer in the 2 months from when the coupon gets added to the customer.

Comment: so how does `duration_in_months` work with annual subscriptions?